# android make the first radio button always selected

Tags: android, sqlite, radio-button

I am developing a quiz application which consists of a question and three options stored in sqlite database and I am using radio buttons for these options. the problem is the first radio button will be selected first time only and when I select for example the second option from question 1 and I go to the next question the second option will remain selected and I want the option 1 to be selected in every question. so if I selected the second option from question 1 in the next question the first option should be selected.

```
my xml code:

<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radio0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checked="true"
android:text="RadioButton" />

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radio1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="RadioButton" />

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radio2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

and I tried using java but it didn't work:

```
RadioButton FirstOption, SecondOption, ThirdOption;   

while(questionID < 10) 
{
FirstOption.isChecked();    
}
```

Comment: `isChecked()` is a test method to see if the radiobutton is checked and returns a boolean. The answer from Mr Radar is correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FirstOption.setChecked(true)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: it didn't work with while loop but it did work with if condition. thanks